# for element in ant build.xml

Tags: junit, ant, ant-contrib

I am using a build.xml(ant) and code looks as follows,

```
<junit fork="yes" dir="." >
----------
---------
<for list="1,2,3,4,5,6" param="Val">
<env key="environment" value="${Val}" />
<batchtest fork="yes" todir="${junitreport.todir}">
    <fileset dir="src/java">
        <include name="TestOne.java" />
        <include name="TestTwo.java" />
    </fileset>
</batchtest>
</for>
</junit>
```

while running this i get the following error,

```
junit doesn't support the nested "for" element.
```

Is there any other way to achieve this loop in junit?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the `<for>` and the `<junit>` elements so `<for>` is on the outside and `<junit>` is on the inside:

```
<for list="1,2,3,4,5,6" param="Val" delimiter=",">
    <sequential>
        <junit ...>
            <!-- Use an at-sign to reference the "param" from "for". -->
            <env key="environment" value="@{Val}" />
        </junit>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

Note, that `Val` is referenced as `@{Val}` with an at-sign (`@`), not a dollar sign (`$`).